# Form Submission with Spring Annotation Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, form-submit

How to handle duplicate form submission in Spring annotation based controller?

Regards,

Raj

Comment: skaffman:what is the wrong with question,if you know please advice,instead of discouraging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller, after processing users supplied data do redirect (instead of forwarding by default) to another page.

Like this:

```
return "redirect:success";
```

See also [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) on Wikipedia